# ¿Cómo abrir un actividad específica desde una notificación push Android?

Tags: android-studio, notificaciones, push

A través de un Tutorial pude lanzar Notificaciones FCM para Android desde mi servidor.

Funciona perfectamente pero me encuentro con estas inquietudes para poder terminar el proyecto:

Actualmente cuando recibo la Notificación, la misma me envía al *MainActivity* (el cual levanta la web/App a través del webview y lo que yo necesito es "que directamente vaya a MainActivity2 (el cual levantaría otro webview con la página de Promociones de la Web.

Espero que me haya explicado bien y agradezco su colaboración.

Dejo el código:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".NotificacionesServicio">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Notificaciones.java:

```
    private void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String title = data.get("title");
        String body = data.get("body");

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "GSdeveloper";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Solo para android Oreo o superior
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            "Mi notificacion",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX
            );

            // Configuracion del canal de notificación
            channel.setDescription("Qué Comemos?");
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            channel.enableVibration(true);

            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("Mensaje", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        CharSequence link = null;
        PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = null;
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name_ic_notification)
                .setTicker("Qué Comemos?")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
                .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo("info");

            manager.notify(1, builder.build());
        }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            enviarNotificacion(remoteMessage);
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String TAG = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "Body notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            enviarNotificacion(remoteMessage);

            
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
            // Set the Activity to start in a new, empty task
            notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            // Create the PendingIntent
            PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
    }



MainActivity2.java:

    public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            WebView webView = this.findViewById(R.id.webviewdos);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    // Habilita el StarActivity para  whatsapp, tel, mailto, etc.
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    //Desabilita el Atar Activity >> Intent intent = null;
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            });


            webView.loadUrl("https://transporteelchanguito.com/app/producto.php?id=8");

            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){
            WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewdos);
            if(wv.canGoBack()){
                wv.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder abrir una actividad desde la notificación puedes usar `addAction(icon, title, intent)` en el código que ya tienes, el primer parámetro es el icono que quieres ponerle, el segundo es el texto que tendrá la opción y el ultimo es el intent que quieres abrir.

Te dejo el ejemplo con una porción de tu código:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("Mensaje", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

CharSequence link = null;
PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = null;
builder.setAutoCancel(true)

        // Aquí agregamos la acción
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_icon, "Abrir actividad", pendingIntent)

        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name_ic_notification)
        .setTicker("Qué Comemos?")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
        .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
        .setContentInfo("info");

manager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#addAction(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) puedes encontrar la documentación para *addAction*.

> ### Edición:
>
> Puedes encontrar un ejemplo para versiones mayores del API 23 en [éste enlace](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#add-reply-action), ya que al parecer `addAction(icon, title, intent)` fue deprecado para API 23 y en su lugar solicitan utilizar `addAction(action)`.
>
> **Ejemplo que se muestra en el enlace**
>
> ```
>  // Create the reply action and add the remote input.
>  NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_reply_icon,
>                getString(R.string.label), replyPendingIntent)
>                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
>                .build();
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  // Build the notification and add the action.
>  Notification newMessageNotification = new Notification.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
>          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
>          .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
>          .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
>          .addAction(action)
>          .build();
>
>  // Issue the notification.
>  NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
>  notificationManager.notify(notificationId, newMessageNotification);
> ```

Comment: Gracias Israel por tu colaboración!
Te cuento que coloqué tu código y funciona pero me doy cuenta que cuando la App está cerrada no abre la Actividad2, me lleva a la App mostrando la Actividad principal (o sea, abre la App y queda ahí).

Comment: Mmmm es extraño, yo uso ese código y me abre normal la actividad que necesito aunque la app este cerrada. Lo único que se me ocurre es que en el manifest agregues el *intent-filter* como `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` para la actividad `MainActivity2`.

Comment: No Israel, no tengo resultado tampoco con este category.
Aprovecho para consultarte una más:

Comment: Quiero capturar el put.Extra("Link") que envío en la NotificacionesServicio.java:

Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
notifyIntent.putExtra("link", remoteMessage.getNotification().getLink());
Bundle miBundle=new Bundle(); miBundle.putString("link", String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getLink()));
notifyIntent.putExtras(miBundle);

Activity2:
Intent notifyIntent = getIntent();
Bundle miBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String link = miBundle.getString("link");
webView.loadUrl(link); // <--- Pero en todos los intentos el dato está vacío...

Comment: Prueba con `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` al usar el *PendingIntent*, algo así: `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

Comment: No hay caso Israel...

Comment:  Perdón Israel, ya solucioné lo de pasar la url de una actividad otra.

Comment: Genial, me alegra ;)

Comment: Solamente me faltaría resolver que me abra la Actividad2 (con la App cerrada) y ya terminaría. Pero de verdad valoro muchísimo y agradezco tu colaboración 